# Конструкция IF в sql functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, функции

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_REPLACE(@id int)

RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN 
( select ............ )
```

Мне нужно добавить конструкцию IF-ELSE внутрь моего селекта.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_REPLACE(@id int)

    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN 
    ( select .....IF () ..... )
```

Прям внутри селекта я сделать это не могу, как я понимаю. Мне нужно объявить переменную, которая будет формироваться на основании IF-ELSE и потом передавать её в селект, или как, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит "внутрь селекта" и какая именно у вас СУБД ? В базовом SQL никакого IF не существует, вместо него CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... А вот в процедурном языке pl/sql есть именно IF, но он к запросам никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: @Mike Я могу сделать через DECLARE? Объявить переменную, содержание которой будет зависеть от IF ELSE и после её использовать в своем sql запросе, так же как переменную, которую принимает функция на вход?

Comment: Это вообще oracle или mssql? Уточните и теги поправьте...

Comment: На каком pl/sql вы хотите это сделать ? этот диалект используется как минимум в Postgersql и Oracle и они разные ... И просто посмотрите в документации на используемую СУБД там обычно масса примеров. И обычно это выглядит просто как `IF x=5 THEN y=10 ELSE y=x END IF`. А внутри селекта вы это то же можете сделать но в виде CASE

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, решил проблему так:
`CREATE FUNCTION GET_REPLACE(@id int)

    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN 
    ( select .....table.x = case when table2.x = 0 then 1 else 0 end   ..... )`

Comment: Есть ещё [IIF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql).